# How can I decode base64 data in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to decode base64 data in TensorFlow?

I looked in the documentation but didn't see any ops.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like :

```
import base64

def base64_decode_op(x):
  return tf.py_func(lambda x: base64.decodestring(x), [x], [tf.string])[0]

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = base64.encodestring("abcd")
base64_decode_op(a).eval()
# prints 'abcd'
```